# Выполнение анимации в JS по очереди

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть код:
http://jsfiddle.net/J8q3M/7/

Нужно, чтобы анимации выполнялись по отдельности, а не одновременно, сначала нужно, чтобы красные цифры дошли до 49, далее зеленые до 82, ну и т.д.

И еще как сделать, чтобы с цифрами стоял знак %?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/J8q3M/10/

Comment: Огромное Спасибо!)